# How to catch selection of saved username password from Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, autofill

I am trying to look how to catch the event from Javascript and process something where user selects a saved username and password from Firefox browser.

I did tricks such as "if browser is Firefox":

1. I check if the password changed and username is focus then I do the other process I needed - this works
2. I kind of polling, perhaps working

But perhaps there is a better way?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a colleague of mine fix this one for me and the js code / pseudo code is as below:

```
if (isFirefox) {
    function triggerEvent(evt) {
        if (evt.originalEvent.inputType == "insertReplacementText") {
            //do what you need here or add your specific logic
        }
    }
    username.on("input", triggerEvent);
    password.on("input", triggerEvent);
}
```

And he directed me a useful link here: https://paul.kinlan.me/monitoring-all-events-on-an-element/